# Is it common to use Drupal's CMS but not its framework?

Tags: drupal

I have created my own site. It comprises a MySQL database, some jQuery and a bunch of PHP files. I decided that I needed a CMS because others will be creating content for the site. I thought about making my own, but it seemed a big task when I considered how to code publication workflows, user roles etc. So I looked for a really light-weight CMS, but everything I looked at wanted me to create page templates, which I don't want to do.

So in the end, I installed Drupal, but rather than re-create my site in Drupal I just created two content types for the two pages that hold created content (articles and blogs). Then I simply re-wrote my SQL queries to grab results from the Drupal MySQL tables rather than the MySQL tables that I created originally. It works fine.

I like this approach because I'm not constrained by the Drupal framework, and I don't have to worry about making my own CMS.

My question: is this a commonly used approach? I don't know what other developers do? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a horrible approach. If youre going to use Drupal/Joomla/Whatever then you should use the CMS/CMF as its intended and if functionality you need doesnt exist then you create the modules/plugins/etc. in the proper fashion to provide that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

"is this a commonly used approach?"

No, it is not. You have violated the incapsulation principle.

1. You can use your own code with Drupal database. But it's better to use the framework as it provides a lot of useful functions: forms creation and validation, DB queries construction etc.
2. It was well tested and your code may contain bugs.
3. If you upgrade Drupal and it changes anything in the database structure - your code may break. If you used standard functions, the modifications will probably be hidden inside them.

Be careful now - you are responsible for the database integrity!

Comment: Thanks. Those are all good points. So, I don't want to re-create my site, but I need a CMS so other people can be authenticated, be assigned roles, manage files/images, create, edit and publish pages. I don't want to make my own CMS. What do you think I should do?

Comment: You can create a custom theme for Drupal and create appropriate modules if necessary. I made this site in Drupal, using this approach: http://www.bikeswitzerland.com/.

Comment: @user1919784: Well thats what you need to do, though "re-create" is probably the wrong term. You need to integrate... meaning you apply your markup as a theme and make changes to that markup where needed by Drupal, and then you adapt your PHP to using the appropriate Drupal APIs and creating custom modules where necessary.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll give integration a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will probably work, and if you had said that you have a complex existing site and you are very limited in time - I would say your approach is fine.

But it seems to me like it is not the case. Given your circumstances, I highly recommend integrating your existing code into Drupal. There are really 2 main reasons why you should do it:

1. Now you only need the article editing feature. But I'm pretty sure somewhere down the road you will find at least one other feature of Drupal that will save you tons of work.
2. Integrating your existing code with drupal is really not as hard as you may think...